# Unable to use the Sandbox Test user Account in iPhone in app purchase

Tags: ios

I created one Test user account in the iTunes Connect. I am using them for in app purchase Testing . 
  I tried to login with those Credentials. Giving Error popup like .
  " The Apple ID has not yet used with the iTunes Store" after clocking ok, Second popup like "The Apple ID has not yet used with the iTunes Store" and please Review.
Here we are testing the in App Purchase . So do we need to give the credit / Debit card Details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have created Test User from the same developer profile from which you have created InApp Purchase Product id.